# feather div edges over background images

Tags: html, css

So I have an image slider behind a div with scrolling text content. I want the edges of the scrolling text div to feather into whatever is displaying behind it, so the text appears/disappears nicely when it scrolls in/out.

I tried adding an inset box shadow and linear gradients, but when the scrolling text has a transparent background you can see the shading around the text, fading into black, rather than transparent.

This is what I have:
[image: mountain background text overlay example one]

This is what I want:
[image: mountain background faded text overlay example two]

How do I do it with CSS?

You shouldn't need my code as it's not a bug, but here's some anyway.

```
<style>
  #slider, #text, #text_overlay {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #slider {
    height: 350px;
  }
  #text, #text_overlay {
    top: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  #text {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  #text_overlay {
    z-index: 20;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 3%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 97%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  }
</style>
<div id="slider">
  <img src='https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg' />
</div>
<div id="text">Some text etc blah blah blah</div>
<div id="text_overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this issue using **-webkit-mask-image** and a gradient as the mask on the text div. No need for the text_overlay div anymore, and works with changing backgrounds :)

```
#text {
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(
        to right, /* gradient direction */
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, /* transparent left 3% */
        rgba(0,0,0,1) 3%, /* visible in the middle start */
        rgba(0,0,0,1) 97%, /* visible in the middle end */ 
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 100% /* transparent right 3% */ 
    );
}
```

Full code:

```
<style>
  #container {
    position:relative;
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #slider, #text {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #slider {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #text {
    top: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(
      to right, /* gradient direction */
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, /* transparent left 3% */
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 3%, /* visible in the middle start */
      rgba(0,0,0,1) 97%, /* visible in the middle end */ 
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 100% /* transparent right 3% */ 
    );
  }
</style>
<div id="container">
  <div id="slider">
    <img src='https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg' />
  </div>
  <div id="text">Some text etc blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```